# Attribute Error: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_numpy_matrix'

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, attributeerror

I am receiving the following error: AttributeError: module `'networkx' has no attribute from_numpy_matrix`
While trying to run the following in PyCharm:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pkg_resources

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, save
from bokeh.models import Range1d, Circle, ColumnDataSource, MultiLine
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.plotting import from_networkx
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 900

network_path = r"D:\MyPython\Framework\matrix2_inverted.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(network_path)
df = df.set_index('0')

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(df.values,
                              parallel_edges=False,
                              create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official `networkx` doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html), there is no method `from_numpy_matrix`, hence the error you are getting.

However, there is the method `from_numpy_array`, documented [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_array.html).

> from_numpy_array(A, [...]) Returns a graph from a 2D NumPy array
>
> The 2D NumPy array is interpreted as an adjacency matrix for the
> graph.
>
> Parameters : A, An adjacency matrix representation of a graph

You could therefore use it instead.

```
G = nx.from_numpy_array(df.values,
                        parallel_edges=False,
                        create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```